# MITM in "Next generation" firewalls becoming a norm?

Tags: firewalls, man-in-the-middle

So I went to a seminar lately and heard about the "SSL inspection" part of Nextgen firewalls. It was basically MITM to be able to monitor the users of the network. Is it becoming a common practice in the real world? Or is this just another insane tech some companies want to push on us?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, it is both. i.e.,

- Employee monitoring is a growing trend. Apparently many companies, large and small, want to monitor their employee activities in the name of security and risk management.
- Vendors (both firewall vendors and other end-point agent based solution vendors) see the demand and cater to it.
- Many IT managers who want to buy latest equipment (so that they can stave off obsolescence as long as possible) get this feature automatically. Once you have the feature, it doesn't take much justification to start using it.